# Db2 Cast to double

Tags: sql, db2

In Db2, how can I cast a number so that it has 1 digit to the left of the decimal and 6 digits to the right? When i use 'Double', it has almost 12 digits to the right. The number will always be a fraction that is between 0 and 1.

I am not able to find the syntax for the double precision Cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `DECIMAL`. For what you want, you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT CAST(D.VALUE AS DECIMAL(7,6)) AS AMOUNT
FROM your_table
```

The first number gives the total amount of digits, and the second is the number after the decimal.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to have 0 --> 0 instead of 0.000000 and 1 --> instead of 1.000000

Comment: Have a look at the [`NORMALIZE_DECFLOAT`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050509.html) function.